# Dojo Build System - custom paths hash not working

Tags: build, dojo, app-config, config

I am trying to switch from the old dojo build system to the new one. I have been pulling my hair out but I can't seem to get the build script to pick up the custom paths mapping that i specified in the building profile. So if my project structure is like:

```
/www/dojo
/www/dojox
/www/dijit
/www/app.profile.js
/www/myapp/package.json      #links to myapp.profile.js
/www/myapp/myapp.profile.js  #standard package profile stub
                             #with test,copyOnly,amd 
/www/myapp/main.js
/www/myapp/bar/hello.js
/www/myapp/bar/sometext.html
```

The files look like below:

```
//-------------------------------------------
//FILE: app.profile.js
//-------------------------------------------
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        basePath: ".",
        releaseDir: "builds",
        releaseName: "v0_0_1",
        optimize: "closure",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        action: "release",

        packages:[
        {
           name: "dojo",
            location: "dojo/dojo"
        },
        {
           name: "myapp",
           location: "myapp"
        }
        ],

        prefixes: {
            "foo": "bar" //doesn't seem to work?
        },

        paths: {
            "foo": "bar" //doesn't seem to work?
        },

        loaderConfig:{
        paths: {
            "foo": "bar"  //doesn't seem to work?
        },
    },      

    layers: {
        "mypp/myapp-release": {
            include: [
                "myapp/main"
            ]
        }
    }
};
})();

//--------------------------------------
//FILE: main.js
//--------------------------------------
require(["dojo/_base/html", "foo/hello", "dojo/text!foo/sometext.html"], 
    function(html, Bar, sometext){
        alert(sometext);
    }
);

//--------------------------------------
//FILE: hello.js
//--------------------------------------
require([ ], 
    function(){
        alert("hello!");
    }
);
```

And I am running the build command with:

```
node /www/dojo/dojo.js load=build /www/app.profile.js
```

The build script would tell me that the dependency "foo/hello" is not found, even though it should have been mapped to bar/hello.js ; the same goes for foo/sometext.html .

Any help would be really appreciated; I don't want to keep pulling my hair til I'm bald! :D